# Is it possible to request the right to study a university course while one is on seemingly endless coronavirus immigration bail on the UK?

Tags: uk, covid-19, study

The way things are going it seems that my bail is just going to be endlessly extended as coronavirus measures are becoming more and more intense.

Without receiving leave to remain or a visa which I may be ineligible for, would it be possible to request from the home office permission to study a university course while here on immigration bail?

I have only been able to find in my online searches materials regarding children studying primary and secondary school, and basic English language classes for non native English speakers.

If so, then how does one go about submitting such a request?

Comment: What is the reason why you're unable to return home? I presume this would decide whether or not such a request might be granted.

Comment: The answer to this question would probably involve a query around finances, which would be difficult - if allowed, you would probably be required to pay the full international student rate, which is a lot for a normal university in the UK (tens of thousands per term) which then leads to the question about how you are supporting yourself - you would have to prove independent wealth with no employment in the UK.

Comment: @Moo How would one go about understanding the process for requesting this and submitting the request?

Comment: @jonathanreez because I intend to appeal my removal using resources that are out of service for reasons of the pandemic and furthermore my country of nationality is especially bad with respect to the pandemic so I don't wish to travel there right now.

Comment: "I do not wish to travel [back to my country]" means nothing to IOs. One of their functions is to remove people who really do not wish to travel back to their countries.

Comment: Yes good point but reducing travel during a final pandemic is slightly different.

Comment: @JosephP. there are flights from the UK to the US, so both governments deem it safe enough to allow travel - and basic precautions such as mask wearing, glove wearing, not touching your face and frequent hand washing can minimise the risk of infection, so I dont see why the current pandemic situation would pose a blocker to deportation or removal.

Comment: Because the government is operating on reduced capacity and so I have been granted immigration bail on their decision, not mine. That is already the given case, so given that I am aiming to gain the right to study in the meanwhile.

Comment: Questions about study visas and other long term migration subjects fall outside the scope of this site. You can ask on our sister site [expatriates.se] Many of your questions stretch the scope covered here. You would do well to look at other Stack Exchange sites where the different focus is likely get you better answers.

Comment: I would expect you could enroll in a university course. Risking however to lose all paid fees if you need to leave before it finishes.

Comment: @Joseph P. The conditions stated in your immigration bail will determine what you are allowed to do. https://www.gov.uk/bail-immigration-detainees/conditions-of-your-bail What do they say regarding studies?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.